# C language error: segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am creating an organisation management software in C language.
Here is my code..

```
struct account {
 char name[200];
 int id;
 struct account* next;
 struct account* prev;
};


void addAccount(struct account* accounts, struct account*  head, struct account* tail){
 if(head == tail){
  accounts->id = 1;
  p("Enter name");
  scanf("%s", accounts->name);
  accounts->id = 1;
  accounts->next = NULL;
  accounts->prev = NULL;
 } else {
  struct account* a = (struct account*)malloc(sizeof(struct account));
  p("Enter name");
  scanf("%s", a->name);
  a->id = tail->id + 1;
  a->next = NULL;
  a->prev = tail;
  tail = a;
 }
 p("Account added");
 // return;
}
```

On calling `addAccount` function, the error coming is..
**[1]    28045 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out**

Please help!

Comment: What specific line did your debugger report as experiencing the problem?  What was passed to this function?  Where is `p` defined?  What input did you enter?

Comment: You aren't changing head or tail.

Comment: There is not enough information in the question to reproduce the problem - you'll need to edit to include a [mcve].  Alternatively, this is a great opportunity to learn to use your debugger.

Comment: We can't really help without knowing what arguments you pass to the function and what it's supposed to do...

Comment: As others have indicated, there isn't enough info here to debug (e.g. did you allocate `head` before calling this?) However, based on your line `tail = a`, I think one problem is that you are assuming you can update the pointer `tail` outside of your function from your function (I think you want to pass a pointer-to-a-pointer for tail).

Comment: This is my main function..

Comment: Please find full code here

Comment: `p` is just a function to print string

Comment: Can someone please comment a solution fast?

Comment: @stark Can you tell where?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OBwaPY2JW4pbsfuA0mV9oekx0A_sbXwq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The linked program doesn't allocate `accounts` initially and never changes the value of `accounts`/`head`/`tail`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.